# Angular 7 - Load File into Assets Folder at Runtime

Tags: node.js, angular, http, angular7

I have a route in my backend that returns a file:

```
app.get('/path', (req, res) => {
    res.send(path.join(__dirname, './myfile.obj'))
})
```

My goal is to load this file at runtime via Angular.

Currently I am trying to do this via an HTTP request but it doesn't seem to work:

```
this.http.get('myurl', { /* my options */ }).subscribe(data => {
    console.log('data', data);
});
```

**I need to be able to "save" the file in the assets folder** (or anywhere else) at runtime, so I can pass the file into the loader via it's location:

```
const objLoader = new OBJLoader();
objLoader.setPath('assets/');
objLoader.load('myfile.obj', (object) => {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: check `responseType`, https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest

Comment: Thank you, that helped! But this was not my only issue... I need to store the file locally to load it via the `objLoader`. Any ideas on thits?

Comment: @Florian Can you please let me know if you get any solution so far?

Comment: @Darshana not so sure. It's been a long time

Answer (score -3):

JSON is the default type returned by http.get as of Angular 7. It will try to parse it as JSON. Look at the overloads for [HttpClient's Get method](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get) and use the appropriate cast.

Comment: You're totaly right, I should have looked there, first! But this is not my only issue... I need to store the file locally to load it via the `objLoader`. Any ideas on thits?